# Rails 3 and memcaching an association

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, memcached, associations

Following.rb

```
belongs_to :show

def cached_show
  Rails.cache.fetch([self, :show]) do
    show      
  end
end
```

View:

```
<% @recently_favorited.each do |following| %>
<li>
  <%= link_to "#{following.cached_show.name}", show_path(:permalink => following.cached_show.permalink) %> <span><%= "(#{pluralize(following.cached_show.followers, "follower")})" %></span>
</li>
<% end %>
```

Result in the console:

```
Cache read: followings/632770-20120929132253/show
Cache generate: followings/632770-20120929132253/show
  Show Load (0.7ms) SELECT `shows`.* FROM `shows`WHERE `shows`.`id` = 617 LIMIT 1
Cache write: followings/632770-20120929132253/show

Cache read: followings/632770-20120929132253/show
Cache fetch_hit: followings/632770-20120929132253/show

Cache read: followings/632770-20120929132253/show
Cache fetch_hit: followings/632770-20120929132253/show
```

Question:
Is this even a "correct" implementation of fetching/caching an association?
And what about performance?
In some views (as in the example) it will hit the cache 3 times per loop. In my case I'm looping 10 items in the footer, so it will make 30 hits on every request. Is this fine, or will a single n+1 query per loop be better?

Advise and general best practices appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a distinct method to hit the cache vs getting it fresh is not common from what I can tell.

Most of the time, you'd just call a method that asks the `cache` all the time, since if you include an object in the cache-key, the `updated_at` field is used to build the key.

For your example now, the weird part is that you don't actually do anything with the `Following` model apart accessing its association. Therefore,  you should query directly on the `Show` model :

```
@recently_favorited_shows = Show.joins(:followings).order("followings.created_at DESC").uniq
```

Then in your view, loop on the shows. Only one query, no n+1

If you expect thousands of hits then, I'd just suggest to cache the result of `@recently_favorited_shows` and expire it every X minutes :

```
@recently_favorited_shows = cache_store.fetch('recently_favorited_shows', expires_in: 5.minutes){Show.joins(:followings).order("followings.created_at DESC").uniq}
```

On another note, here's a good write-up on cache usage on the view side if you want to do it some time: http://37signals.com/svn/posts/3113-how-key-based-cache-expiration-works

#### No joins solution

Edit : now, if you have gazillions of rows in `followings` table, here's what I'd do :

- Create a field `last_followed_at` on the `shows` table, with an index on it
- In `Following.rb` : `belongs_to :show, touch: :last_followed_at`. This way, as soon as you add a new entry in `Following`, it'll update the field on the `shows` table
- Then, to get the latest followed shows, do :

  ```
  @shows = Show.order("last_followed_at DESC").limit(10) # Fast query of course
  ```

Comment: Your query didn't even finish within 1 minute in my development environment. I might missing a index, I'm not sure, but I think it would be slow anyway to join so much (like 1M rows). I'll cache the result of two queries instead.

Comment: Consider adding indexes and a limit to the request since you don't need all the shows but the latest `n` shows

Comment: No, I need the latest `n` followings :) Sorry for not posting that code.

Comment: Edited my answer so you don't do any joins since you'll have a big data set

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer my question, but it solves my problem. Here's how I'll do it instead:

```
@shows = Rails.cache.fetch("recently_favorited_shows", expires_in: 1.minutes) do
  Show.find(Following.order("created_at DESC").limit(10).collect(&:show_id))
end
```

The queries are pretty fast (~0.8ms each says the IRB console)

Comment: You can make the query a tiny bit faster if you replace that last method call. Instead of `.limit(10).collect(&:show_id)`, try using `.limit(10).pluck(:show_id)`. Returns an array of show ids directly without instantiating the Following objects first, which it would have to GC later.